# Proper way to do dynamic jquery buttons

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Here's my scenario:

I have content dynamically generated out of a mySQL database. I want to have quantities and add to cart buttons for each item in the list (30-several hundred per page). Normally in javascript I would use a function for onSubmit whose values were created in the PHP loop. I know that is bad practice and is frowned upon.

So how would I go about using jquery to get the information from the form based on the button that was clicked?

Comment: What have you tried? Nobody is going to do this work for you from scratch. You'll need to make an attempt, at least.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't have the jquery on this machine to actually grab the code, but I know from previous questions that it's best to make listeners in the jquery document.ready. I imagine I would have to do some DOM traversal, so the listeners grabs the button by class or something when it is pressed, then jquery will grab the content of its sibling form elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP, add a `data-...` attribute to the button, including the item ID or whatever unique identifier is needed:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <button  data-id="1">add</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    Item ID 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Quantity: <input type="number" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

In jQuery, this can be referenced via the `.data()` method:

```
var itemid = btn.data('id');
```

you can use `.closest()` to find the button's container, and from there, other relevant data:

```
$('button').click(
  function()
  {
    var btn = $(this);
    var itemid = btn.data('id');
    var row = btn.closest('tr');
    var inp = row.find('input');
    var qty = inp.val();
    addSomething(itemid, qty);
  }
);
```

Example CodePen: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/GzIhg

Comment: how could I get multiple inputs, including hidden ones?

Comment: Hidden doesn't matter. You could select them by name (`input[name=foo]`), by class (`input.myclass`), by type (`input[type=password]`), etc.

Comment: Would that be inp = row.find(input[name=foo]) or qty = row.(input[name=foo]).val()? Sorry, still learning jquery.

Comment: `row.find("input[name=foo]").val()`